# Cannot find lodash.js

Tags: laravel, npm, vue.js, lodash

I get this error in my browser console:

> app.js:26089 Uncaught Error: Module build failed: Error: ENOENT: no
>   such file or directory, open
>   '/Users/me/code/laravel/myproject/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js'

It can't find lodash.js while the file exists:

```
me@macbook:~$ ls -l /Users/me/code/laravel/myproject/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js
-rw-r--r--  1 me  staff   527K Feb  4 08:30 /Users/me/code/laravel/myproject/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js
```

How should I fix this issue ?

Comment: doesn't the URL to lodash need to be relative to the root of your app instead of absolute?

Comment: How are you including the lodash module?

Comment: @btl It's in my package.json: `    "devDependencies": {
        "axios": "^0.17",
        "bootstrap": "^4.0.0",
        "cross-env": "^5.1.3",                                                                                                                                                       
        "jquery": "^3.3.1",
        "lodash": "^4.17.5",
        "popper.js": "^1.13.0",
        "vue": "^2.5.13"
    },`

Comment: @maxagaz that's how you've included the dependency in your project. How are you including it in your code? It will be something like `import` or `require`

Comment: @Phil It's by default in Laravel's bootstrap.js file: `window._ = require('lodash');`